# How to display label field one by one with every 5 secs in windows application?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, windows

hi i have to display label in windows form in every 5 secs in windows application.
I have five labels with different signature so i have to display the lable one by one in windows form . please help me to do it.

Comment: use a timer to display the labels

Comment: You should explain your question more clearly. Provide sample codes, etc.

Comment: use a timer and toggle visiblity properties of the controls. However this is no question but a request to design a solution.

Comment: have you tried something ? !!

Answer (score 0):

Set the `time.interval = 5000`. This will make your timer tick every 5 seconds. Inside the timer you can have the labels and each tick enable a text box using `textbox.enabled = true`.